# I need to groom my dog during this covid lockdown

Tags: dogs, grooming

Posting for a friend.

She has a poodle cross dog and his coat has grown and needs grooming. Its also curly and dense.

She wants to know can she just take a clipper to him and go for it or whether clipping the odd bit of fur to neaten him up will do.

Id like to know if anyone has done this and what they did or what advice would you offer for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily clip a dog, you just want to make sure you have proper control of the dog while clipping so you don't accidentally cut them. 
You first want to bathe the dog and get them very clean. If you can use some sort of pet-friendly conditioner, I recommend using that as well because it will make the fur easier to clip. Make extra sure they are totally dry before clipping or you could cause the blades to rust.

I recommend using clippers like Wahl that you can order online. If you want to really invest, Oster is a great brand.

As always, be careful and give lots of treats. So your dog gets used to the sound and feel of the clipper, hold the back of the clipper against their body a few times so they get used to the vibrations. Every so often, you will want to turn the clippers off and let them rest because they can get hot.

Answer (score 0):

Bathing (and conditioning) the dog really helps to soften the fur before cutting it. (Same goes for nails). Even in the absence of professional grooming, you can keep them brushed to avoid big mats from forming. If you are bathing your dog at home, please brush his coat before bathing so that there's no mats as a result of tangles. Also, make sure the water pressure is low and the water is lukewarm.

Whenever your pets come back from walks, clean their paws with pet wipes thoroughly and move a wipe across their body as well. Wash their leashes and collars after the walk and dry them out in the sun.

If you have pet clippers, it’s OK to go for it, but don’t put scissors anywhere near your dog.

Hope these links help ([Grooming](https://dogwithblog.in/dog-grooming-tips/), [DIY grooming at home](https://dogwithblog.in/how-to-groom-your-dog-at-home/))

Comment: This looks like it's promoting a site, and we do not allow that. When providing links, it's important to include the pertinent details in the answer, so the post is self contained.